# What are the risks of installing (running) foreign npm modules? Can we limit the risks?

Tags: node.js, security, npm, permissions

According to [this post](https://medium.com/@liran.tal/malicious-modules-what-you-need-to-know-when-installing-npm-packages-12b2f56d3685), malicious npm modules are real.  And it seems the only real approach is to "be aware of what you're installing."

When I `npm install` and `require()` a module,

- Could it access my entire file system?
- Can I limit the file system access to a specific directory?  Either with a `package.json` setting, or maybe with the OS's native user/groups file permission system?
- Could it execute any commands?  Download anything, execute anything, upload anything?
- Can I restrict this?

Answer (score 0):

An npm package (like any library/software) has the full access to whatever environment you put it in. If you can do it in Node.js, an npm package can do it.
As a package manager, npm can effectively put a file anywhere (ex. an malicious executable) and when a function is called it can do whatever it was programmed to (ex. execute the malware).

Software auditing is real, and a major push is being done by various Open Source groups to help make sure that software doesn't have any critical flaws (intentional or otherwise). Before you install, find the package.json file and give it a read, if something seems suspicious you might have to dig deeper (ask a dev or community member for help). If the software is open source look for audits (or audit yourself).

There are some suggestions listed in this Medium article: https://medium.com/@nodepractices/were-under-attack-23-node-js-security-best-practices-e33c146cb87d

Recommendation: Try to be a white hat hacker. Check out the technology and try to infect your own machine with some malicious code you made, then see if there's a way you could have avoided it.

Source:
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the only way to prevent this is to "be aware of what you're installing."

Short answer: **When you require a module, it becomes your code**

- Could it access my entire file system ?: YES it can ! [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) and [chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) require native fs module
- Can I limit the file system access to a specific directory?: No you can't ! As I said above, it becomes your code once you require it. You can't or don't want to limit access to yourself...
- Could it execute any commands? : Yes it can ! [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) can do it
- Can I restrict this? : Yes you can: Don't be lazy ! Do not install any module for small tasks like set environment, set CORS setup etc... ! Try to achieve it yourself with natives Nodejs's elements.

The essential modules of are generally audited and used by millions of senior developers around the world.

Comment: You can be aware of the modules that you are explicitly installing.  However, when you install a module with npm, it typically pulls in many dependent modules (some of which have their own dependencies).   For a larger project, you may explicitly require a couple dozen modules, but end up pulling in several hundred dependencies, which makes auditing much harder.